# how to write the following terminal command in applescript and schedule it

Tags: applescript

I need to set up a schedule to delete a set of files on a daily basis. I am new to mac and can't get my head around applescript at the moment.

This is the terminal command I need to use

```
rm -R /Volumes/Home/RBPY/Final\ Cut\ Libraries/*.fcpbundle/*/Render\ Files
```

I also need to schedule it to run every day at 10pm just before my backup occurs. this clears away bloat caused by FCPX

I have set up a schedule that runs it in Power Manager, but would prefer an in house script that runs. It seems so simple but I am struggling.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Execute a shell command from Applescript like this:

do shell script "rm -R /Volumes/Home/RBPY/Final\ Cut\ Libraries/*.fcpbundle/*/Render\ Files"

iCal can schedule scripts through an event alarm. Create an event that repeats regularly and connect your executable script as an alarm.

Since your script is very much shell and not at all Applescript perhaps you'd want go for an all-shell-script. OSX provides launchd to automatically run scripts. launchd starts per-User launch-agents from /Users/blabla/Library/LaunchAgents. The files in that directory use xml-plist files to tell launchd what script to start under which conditions. The script you specify is one line of unix-code (could be a call to a shell script).

Comment: I get an error when I run this -- rm: /Volumes/Home/RBPY/FinalCut Libraries/.fcpbundle//Render Files: No such file or directory   I have considered Launchd, but not sure how to launch it, or write in it even. Can you give me some pointers.

Comment: OK I think I am getting it. I have written a trial plist in gedit but when I try to save it, I get an error that I do not have the correct permissions to save it. In Linux I would have opened Gedit using sudo from the terminal, but when I do that in mac I get a command not found error. I could use nano but I am not familiar with that one.